# Postsharp/Reflection Conflict

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, aop, postsharp

I wanted to make 2 basic classes `Entity` and `EntityCollection` and to inherent all my data classes from them. In Entity class constructor I wanted to call this method:

```
   public static void InitAllCollection(Object o)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in o.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            if (!propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsConstructedGenericType ||
                propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof (EntityCollection<>)) continue;

            var ctor = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredConstructors
                .Where(c => !c.GetParameters().Any())
                .Select(c => c).FirstOrDefault();
            propertyInfo.SetValue(o, ctor.Invoke(new object[0]));
        }
    }
```

This method was automatically init all `EntityCollection` member of entity, so I don't need to duplicate code.

And everything worked fine until I introduces post sharp aspect of `NotifyPropertyChanged` aspect. After that calling`propertyInfo.SetValue(o, ctor.Invoke(new object[0]));` is trowing `TargetInvocationException`.

Can I somehow tell postsharp to exclude `EntityCollection` generics or at least to exlude them before constrictor is finished.

**EDIT:** `InitAllCollection` method is called during `Entity` constructor. Also it is project for Windows 8.1

Comment: Which PostSharp version do you use? When is InitAllCollection called? This works well for me, what is different in your case? https://gist.github.com/JakubLinhart/d93070f4d096e98ac9d2

Comment: I am using latest stable version of PostSharp.  InitAllCollection is called during Entity constructor

Comment: It works even from constructor and windows store app. So there is some other difference between your case and my example...